# Java custom tag with JS

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, custom-tags

I have custom tag which contains `form` with `text input` and `submit`. I want to validate this `text input` using JS, so my custom tag output should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(form) {
        var text = form.textInput;
        // validation code
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit='return validate(this);'>
    <input type='text' name='textInput'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

*(Note, this code simplified!)*

My problem appears when I want to use this tag twice or more times at page - I want to print `form` at page again, but not JS validation code! Validation code must be unique at the page. How can I archive that? My custom tag extends `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the most suitable solution for me.

Class `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport` contains protected field `pageContext` which presents... page context! I can easily access context attributes of `javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext`. So, I put next code in my custom tag:

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    if (pageContext.getAttribute("validated") == null) {
        // validation code writing
        pageContext.setAttribute("validated", true);
    }
    ...
}
```

If condition would be reachable only once per page rendering.

Hope it would be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to try to embed that JavaScript function in some .js file an import that file. If you don't want to do that, for some reason you should try to define that function dynamically, if it is not defined:

```
if (typeof window.validateMyForm === 'undefined') {
    window.validateMyForm = function(form) {
        var text = form.textInput;
        // validation code
    }
}
```

As you guess this should define function only if it is not already defined.

First answer is correct, but that means that programer must know where in code are already inserted custom tags and according to that this whether to set that parameter to true or false. And what about code changes, you will have to always go thought whole page and revise all used tags on a page.

Comment: But your suggestion means, that I should to place this code at the page every time I call my custom tag)

Comment: No, my suggestion is to replace your Javascript code in your custom component, with this. But with this code you should not have collision between defined JavaScript functions.

Comment: But every time I call my tag, it will place JS code at .html page!

Comment: I wrote this as alternative, this will place code, but function will be defined just once as opposite to your definition. At first my suggestion was to define function in js file, and import that file at the begging of the page.

Comment: I can write this code directly in the head of page, but it's not good. Custom tag must be separated from application, is it clear? also, is it possible to access page object from custom tag? (like js 'document' object)

Answer (score 1):

Make the custom tag to accept a parameter that toggles the validation on or off, and of course have it generate different code depending on the value of the parameter.